# SharePoint 2016 SSA categories count showing 0

Tags: central-administration, managed-property, 2016, crawled-property, searchserviceapplication

All Categories in Search Service Application shows count zero. Due to this Managed Property is not able to create from Crawled Properties using PowerShell, as here in this case *SharePoint* category has zero count.

```
$category = "SharePoint"
#Get the Search Service Application
$searchapp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication

#Get the Search Service Application
$cat = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCategory –SearchApplication $searchapp –Identity $category
```

[image]

Any work around or idea ?

Answer (score 0):

See this thread and the MSFT support response. I tested the powershell and it does then allow you to script managed properties, but doesn't resolve this screen's 0's

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/749301b1-c798-4d39-8cf0-5698603c1d26/crawled-properties-not-shown-via-powershell?forum=SP2016